# WSL 2 does not have all memory available to it

Tags: windows-10, memory, wsl2

I know most questions around WSL/2 are about *reducing* memory usage, but mine is a little different. I have 32 GB available in Windows, but WSL2 is only allowing me to use up to 24 of that. Is there anyway to make sure all the memory Windows has is also available in WSL? Or is that reserved for the system for a specific reason?

Windows Build:

```
PS C:\Users\dakot> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      19044  0
```

`wsl.conf` does not exist in Ubuntu WSL instance:

```
dakota@DESKTOP-1KK3IBB:~$ cat /etc/wsl.conf
cat: /etc/wsl.conf: No such file or directory
dakota@DESKTOP-1KK3IBB:~$ ls /etc | grep wsl
dakota@DESKTOP-1KK3IBB:~$
```

`.wslconfig` is not found in my `%UserProfile%` directory:

```
PS C:\Users\dakot> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\dakot


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----          3/2/2022   9:46 AM                .aws
d-----          3/2/2022   9:46 AM                .azure
d-----          3/1/2022   8:22 AM                .docker
d-----         2/28/2022   3:31 PM                .dotnet
d-----         2/28/2022   2:50 PM                .gnupg
d-----          3/1/2022   8:07 AM                .vscode
d-r---         2/28/2022   1:48 PM                3D Objects
d-r---         2/28/2022   1:48 PM                Contacts
d-r---          3/1/2022   1:15 PM                Desktop
d-r---          3/1/2022   7:43 AM                Documents
d-r---          3/2/2022  11:29 AM                Downloads
d-r---         2/28/2022   1:48 PM                Favorites
d-r---         2/28/2022   1:48 PM                Links
d-r---         2/28/2022   1:48 PM                Music
dar---          3/1/2022  12:32 PM                OneDrive
d-r---         2/28/2022   1:49 PM                Pictures
d-----         2/28/2022   2:35 PM                Postman
d-r---         2/28/2022   1:48 PM                Saved Games
d-r---         2/28/2022   1:49 PM                Searches
d-----          3/1/2022   9:30 PM                source
d-r---         2/28/2022   3:05 PM                Videos
d-----          3/1/2022   8:14 AM                wkspaces
-a----         2/28/2022   2:46 PM            144 .gitconfig
-a----         2/27/2022  10:08 PM            780 id_ecdsa
```

WSL is running Version 2:

```
PS C:\Users\dakot> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your [wsl.conf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#wslconf) and [.wslconfig](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#wslconfig) files.  You also need to include which build you are on.  There is a hard 80% limit on certain builds.  If you need more memory than 80% you will have to upgrade to Windows 11.  WSL VMs are limited to 80% on builds before 20175.

Comment: I am fairly new to Windows, I'm not finding `~/.wslconfig` in my Powershell or Explorer.

Comment: I linked to the Microsoft documentation on those two files. One is located at `%UserProfile%\.wslconfig` and wsl.conf is located in `/etc` provided it's WSL version 2. I only need .wslconfig since thats the file that contains the memory configuraton

Comment: Updated post with some output to show that I'm not finding those config files in either Windows or WSL.

Comment: The 80% statement on the linked page, can be taken several ways, considering 24GB is 80% of 32GB I am taking it as you are running an eligible build for the 80% rule to apply (despite the fact you are NOT running 20175).  You might have to create a new WSL2 instance to generate those configuration files.

Comment: [20175 is a pre-Windows 11, Windows 10 Insider Preview build, from before it was turned into Windows 11.](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/07/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20175/).  It's long expired and cannot actually be used, any features contained within it, apply to Windows 11.

Comment: You will never be able to use all (available) memory with WSL 2. It’s just not possible with VMs and a hypervisor as heavy as Hyper-V + Windows. Consider using WSL 1.

Comment: @Ramhound Not quite sure the numbers are syncing up there.  24GB would be 66.6% of 32GB.  This doesn't match the 50% or 80% number noted in the `.wslconfig` doc.  Also note that neither `.wslconfig` (in Windows) nor `/etc/wsl.conf` (in WSL) are ever auto-generated.  They must always be created by the user.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how you are determining that WSL is allowing 24GB?  On my Windows 11 system with 32GB, a `top` command in WSL shows that 16GB is available to WSL.  This is in line with the doc that @Ramhound linked to, with 50% of the total system RAM being available to (but not necessarily consumed by) WSL.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - Check the links I provided in my first. 80% of 32 GB is 25.6 GB. Author themselves said 24 GB, granted I thought they said 26 GB, but it’s close enough. I was totally guessing on why the author was able to use more than 50%. Didn’t know about the files not being generated

Comment: @Ramhound Right - I'm using those docs as reference.  Just thinking that the OP said 24GB, but never mentioned how they arrived at that number.  It seems more likely to me that WSL2 really is providing the 50% number as documented.

Comment: I was determining the 24GB through htop. I'm not entirely sure why those config files were not generated when I created the WSL2 instance (possibly because it was initially created through Docker?). However, I was able to increase it by a bit following the accepted answer. I guess my hope was more that I could use htop to monitor resources used by both systems so I was expecting to see the resources match, but I understand, now, that that is a pipe dream.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Preface*

> Is there anyway to make sure all the memory Windows has is also available in WSL?  Or is that reserved for the system for a specific reason?

"All" memory?  No.  Windows has to have something to run in, and it's not a lightweight OS by any means.  4GB is the minimum system requirement for Windows 11.  It can probably get away with a little less than that, but it's not a good idea.

"Specific purpose"?  There are many, really.  Your desktop, taskbar, network stack, GPU (especially if integrated), dozens of services (see the "Services" plugin) such as the event log, etc. etc. etc.

Not to mention needing room left over for any applications such as your web browser.

However, if you really do need to increase the amount of memory available to WSL2, then read on.

*Short answer:*

First confirm the actual amount of memory currently available to WSL2 via `top`.  Then, if you really do need to increase it:

Close WSL, then from PowerShell:

```
Write-Output "[wsl2]
memory=26GB" >> "${env:USERPROFILE}\.wslconfig"

wsl --shutdown
```

And restart WSL.  Note that this command will only work properly as long as you don't have an existing `.wslconfig` (which you have confirmed you don't).  After running that command once, you'll need to manually edit the file to make future changes.

*Explanation:*

As noted in the doc that Ramhound linked in the comments, the amount of memory available to WSL2 can be adjusted through the use of a `.wslconfig` file.  It can be either decreased (as you note is usually the case), or increased (as I have just confirmed on my system).

If your system is allowing 24GB of usage in WSL, then that may be a combination of system memory and swap.

You don't mention how you are checking the amount of memory, but the "easy way" is to just run the `top` command in WSL:

You'll see something like:

```
top - 20:08:13 up 0 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:   5 total,   1 running,   4 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15955.3 total,  15581.8 free,    275.7 used,     97.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   4096.0 total,   4096.0 free,      0.0 used.  15469.9 avail Mem
```

I have a feeling that your WSL probably has 16GB by default, but I may be wrong.

After changing mine from 16GB to 24GB using the method noted about, I have the following:

```
top - 19:54:19 up 3 min,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
Tasks:   9 total,   1 running,   8 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 24039.29+total, 23622.06+free,  291.879 used,  125.352 buff/cache
MiB Swap: 6144.000 total, 6144.000 free,    0.000 used. 23477.43+avail Mem
```

You'll notice that the available swap also increased, since it is configured (by default) as 25% of the available memory.  This can also be controlled through `.wslconfig`.